# Mapping issue while mapping DNA seq data to transcriptome using bowtie2

Tags: linux, shell, mapping, dna-sequence, bowtie2

I am trying to map DNA seq data to transcriptome using bowtie2, and the DNA seq shows reads mapping to other sets of transcriptome, even though probes used for fishing DNA is designed from set 1 of transcriptome

[These are the parameters I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK18m.png)

Comment: This type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and will very likely be closed here, as it is not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.